# The estimate of the sum of $\frac{\log p_i}{p_i}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $p_i$ denote the i-th prime, we know the following estimate:
$$
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\log p}{p}=\log x+O(1)
$$

But when I’m trying to solve a problem, i need to get the following estimate:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\log p_i}{p_i}=O(\log n)
$$
Is it also true? Thanks to all your reply!

Comment: Hint: use the previous estimate with $x=p_n$ and the prime number theorem, in order to answer your question.

Comment: If $p_n$ is about $n \log n$  then letting $x=n \log n$ would make $\log x = \log n + \log \log n$ which is indeed $O(\log n)$.  Small improvements to the estimate of $p_n$ will not change this result

Comment: @TheOscillator The condition PNT can be weakened to Chebyshev bounds. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, we have

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n{\log p_i\over p_i}
=\sum_{p\le p_n}{\log p\over p}
=\log p_n+\mathcal O(1)
$$

Chebyshev's theorem guarantees the existence of positive constants $A$ and $B$ such that

$$
An\log n<p_n<Bn\log n
$$

Taking logarithms gives

$$
\log n+\log\log n+\log A<\log p_n<\log n+\log\log n+\log B
$$

This implies $\log p_n\sim\log n$. Consequently, we get

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n{\log p_i\over p_i}=\mathcal O(\log n)
$$

Answer (score 0):

You want to say that $$\log p_n=O(\log n)$$

This follows from $$m\le {2m\choose m}=\sum_{p^k\le 2m}\log p (\lfloor \frac{2m}{p^k}\rfloor-2\lfloor \frac{m}{p^k}\rfloor)\le \sum_{p^k\le 2m}\log p$$ $$\le\log(2m) \sum_{p^k\le 2m}1\le \log(2m)^2\pi(2m) $$

Taking $m=p_n/2$ gives the bound $$p_n/2\le \log(p_n)^2 \pi(p_n)= \log(p_n)^2 n $$
Taking the $\log$ of both side gives your result.